# Suspicious downvotes on recently asked questions

Tags: support, down-votes

I noticed that most of the recent questions that are **not closed** since Oct 12 until now (Oct 16) have been downvoted at least once:

- [Can 2 elements be combined into a new release without a "clan based Kekkai Genkai"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49153/can-2-elements-be-combined-into-a-new-release-without-a-clan-based-kekkai-genka)
- [Is Gaara able to control sand because of his mother or shukaku (the 1 tails)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49154/is-gaara-able-to-control-sand-because-of-his-mother-or-shukaku-the-1-tails)
- [Trying to find a song from Assassination Classroom episode 5 season 1](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49159/trying-to-find-a-song-from-assassination-classroom-episode-5-season-1)
- [Is there a mind link between the Gedo Mazo and its summoner](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49164/is-there-a-mind-link-between-the-gedo-mazo-and-its-summoner)
- [How did Moegi learn to use wood release](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49165/how-did-moegi-learn-to-use-wood-release)
- [Where to watch Tokyo ghoul season 3,4](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49166/where-to-watch-tokyo-ghoul-season-3-4)
- [Is Dabi Endeavor's son?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/is-dabi-endeavors-son)
- [At what point did the Kyuubi stop sucking Naruto's chakra](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49170/at-what-point-did-the-kyuubi-stop-sucking-narutos-chakra)
- [Why was EVA Unit 01 Crucified?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49182/why-was-eva-unit-01-crucified)
- [What is Japanese version of the pun word, "slife"? ... and term for adult friend?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49183/what-is-japanese-version-of-the-pun-word-slife-and-term-for-adult-friend)
- [Is Levi Ackerman of Asian descent, like Mikasa?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49188/is-levi-ackerman-of-asian-descent-like-mikasa)
- [Is the talisman a form of cursed seal?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49205/is-the-talisman-a-form-of-cursed-seal)
- [Is Ash's explanation for the origins of his name correct?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49206/is-ashs-explanation-for-the-origins-of-his-name-correct)
- [Are other pirates than the strawhats able to find raftel?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49210/are-other-pirates-than-the-strawhats-able-to-find-raftel)

Out of all questions since then, **only 1** didn't get any downvote: [Do dolls in Rozen Maiden live like a human?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49161/do-dolls-in-rozen-maiden-live-like-a-human)

I observed that all of *Naruto* questions were asked by the same asker; whether it's considered as serial voting or not, I'll rest the case to mods. However, **the rest of the series** (*Assassination Classroom*, *Tokyo Ghoul*, *My Hero Academia*, *Evangelion*, *Reincarnated as Slime*, *Attack on Titan*, *Dragon Ball*, *Banana Fish*, *One Piece*) ticked my suspicion, whether it was done by a single user or not. It also seems that older questions that got bumped (i.e. "active" tab) were ignored, so it seems the voter is looking at the "newest" tab.

Note that **I haven't downvoted any of them** since I don't have much knowledge in those series. While I acknowledge I'm one of the most prolific voters on this site, I didn't/couldn't see the reason to downvote on some of the listed questions. Of course, I also know that voting is anonymous, so I don't expect anyone to justify their votes anywhere (but feel free if you want).

Is my suspicion justified? If it is, then is it possible for mods to investigate/escalate this issue to CM, and whether to invalidate the votes if they are indeed bogus?

Comment: Seems certainly justified, solely judging from [The anime scientists](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/42685/the-anime-scientist?tab=reputation) profile, of which you linked several questions. I'll take a closer look

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for bring attention to this matter. While this indeed does seem to be a targeted incident, at the moment it has been mostly [contained](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/42685/the-anime-scientist?tab=reputation) by SE's internal system.

We will monitor this situation to make sure that such behavior does not escalate further -- over here or to other communities in which the user may participate in. Hopefully the downvoter in question will realize the futility of their actions.

In the meantime, if you are concerned, I would ask you to give the user some upvote to questions or answers they may have that you believe merit them. Downvotes (-2/0) are easily offset by upvotes (+10/+5), after all.